# How do I automate getting BigQuery billing data?

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using BigQuery rather heavily now and I've been tasked with keeping track of how much we are spending on queries each day. There seems to be no easy way to do this within BigQuery? Has anyone else done this already?

I started trying to scrape it myself, but its a real mess. Retrieving data involves a POST to https://bpui0.google.com/billing/ui/batchservice which sends the entire contents of my about:plugins to Google for every new request.

Answer (score 0):

There are two components for BigQuery pricing: Data storage, and data processed by each query.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/pricing#table

To keep track of daily spend, you'd want to track how much data is being processed. An easy way to do this is to look at the 'bytes_processed' field that comes with each API query response.

You could even pipe this data back to BigQuery, to further dice and analyze usage :).